# Numba jit nopython mode: tell numba the signature of an external arbitrary function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I need to build a dissimilarity matrix for a generic metric. Since I need the algorithm to run fast, I used `numba` 0.35 in `nopython` mode.
Here is my code

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from jellyfish import levenshtein_distance

def _dissimilarity_matrix(metric):
    @jit(nopython=True)
    def dm(data):
        n = data.shape[0]
        diss = np.zeros((n, n))
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i+1):
                dist = metric(data[i], data[j])
                diss[i, j] = dist
                diss[j, i] = dist
        return diss

    return dm

@jit(nopython=True)
def euclidean_distance(vec1, vec2):
    return np.sqrt(((vec1 - vec2)**2).sum())

test1 = np.random.randn(10, 2)
dissimilarity_matrix1 = _dissimilarity_matrix(euclidean_distance)
diss1 = dissimilarity_matrix1(test1)

test2 = np.array(["this", "is", "a", "test"])
dissimilarity_matrix2 = _dissimilarity_matrix(levenshtein_distance)
diss2 = dissimilarity_matrix2(test2)
```

but the output is:

```py
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'metric': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
File "test.py", line 12
```

Note that the function `euclidean_distance` is defined by me and has the decorator `@jit(nopython=True)`, while the function `levenshtein_distance` comes from an external module (not written by me). Is there a way to tell `numba` explicitly the signature of the function passed in (i.e. `metric` in `_dissimilarity_matrix`)?
I really need the function `_dissimilarity_matrix` to run in `nopython` mode and accept as input an arbitrary function.

Comment: You can't call arbitrary Python functions in nopython mode. That's the core, defining feature of nopython mode: no Python.

Comment: So if I don't define all functions by myself and let them run in `nopython` mode, there is no way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works for me when `metric` is `euclidean_distance` because that's a function that's also a `nopython` jitted numba function. You can't pass in arbitrary functions though. In order for something to work in `nopython` mode, every callable function must be supported by numba (see http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html and http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html) or be user-defined as a numba `nopython` function. There's no getting around that constraint.

Comment: Thank you. Not even something like `jit(levenshtein_distance)` or `njit(levenshtein_distance)` will do it, right? I have to write my own function decorated with `@jit(nopython=True)`.

Comment: If `levenshtein_distance` was written in such a way that numba could jit it, then it would work, but it would have to adhere to the supported features in the links I provided to do so.